# ORA-02303 cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents, JSON_OBJECT_INVALID on upgrade to Oracle 19c

Tags: json, oracle, upgrade, oracle19c

During upgrade to Oracle 19c the following error may occur:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE JSON_Object_T AUTHID CURRENT_USER UNDER JSON_Element_T(
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the file 'catjsont.sql'.
The bug number is 31913650 in case you want to contact Oracle to request a patch.

You can also make two changes to catjsont.sql and rerun it to fix the issue.

The two types JSON_OBJECT_T and JSON_SCALAR_T needs to be created with FORCE option.
(This is already the case for JSON_ELEMENT_T, JSON_ARRAY_T but not for JSON_OBJECT_T and JSON_SCALAR_T).

The correct statements are

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE JSON_Object_T FORCE AUTHID CURRENT_USER UNDER JSON_Element_T(...
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE JSON_Scalar_T FORCE AUTHID CURRENT_USER UNDER JSON_Element_T(...
```